# Trying to reopen closed popup window

Tags: javascript, popup, window.open

I can't understand what is the reason that makes these 2 scripts written in javascript behave in different ways.

Script 1

```
var w;
function f1() {
    w = window.open("pg1.html","wind","left=0,top=0,width=480,height=480");
}
function f2() {
    w.close();
}
function f3() {
    w.open("pg1.html","wind","left=0,top=0,width=480,height=480");
}
```

Script 2

```
function f() {
    var w = window.open("pg1.html","wind","left=0,top=0,width=480,height=480");
    w.close();
    w.open("pg1.html","wind","left=0,top=0,width=480,height=480");
}
```

In case of script 1, if i execute `function f1()`, then `f2()` (as you can see `f1()` creates new window object and assigns the reference to that object to variable `w`, `f2()` closes window object created by `f1()`) and try to execute function `f3()` afterwards, closed popup window (`w`) doesn't open and in Firefox 19 I get error:

> Error: NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE: Component returned failure code:
>   0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE) [nsIDOMJSWindow.open],

In IE8 I get error:

> The object invoked has disconnected from its clients,

In Chrome 25 I get no errors.

Execution of script 2 (`function f()` that creates new window object, assigns the reference to that object to variable `w`, closes created window and then tries to reopen it) doesn't cause any errors in browsers, but in Firefox  `f()` makes closed popup window reopen, while in IE and Chrome the popup window (`w`) remains closed.

Could You please try these two scripts and help me to understand the reason of such strange behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I hope you are not up to doing what the question implies. Then, I ran the following in firebug console and got different references for sample 2 and 3:

```
console.log('sample 1', w); // undefined
f1();
console.log('sample 2', w); // Window about:blank
f2();
console.log('sample 3', w); // Window
```

It appears `w.close();` destroys the reference to the new window.

Comment: The reason why i didn't get error in Chrome was that i ran Chrome with --allow-file-access-from-files flag. Without this flag i get following error message in Chrome when trying to execute `f3()` after `f1()` and `f2()` have being executed: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'open'. But why does Firefox reopen closed window when executing script2 (function `f()`)?